# Include test run id in k6 metrics sent to Datadog

Tags: javascript, load-testing, datadog, k6

I use k6 on my local machine to perform load-testing as well as a [Datadog agent](https://k6.io/docs/results-visualization/datadog) to visualize the metrics in Datadog.

**I'd like to filter k6 metrics in Datadog as the tests aren't distinguishable.**

At this point the `$test_run_id` only shows `*` (refer to the screenshot below):
[image]

I followed [this the official doc](https://k6.io/docs/cloud/integrations/cloud-apm) that suggests to set `include_test_run_id` flag to `true` in k6 config, but I was unsuccessful.

Here's a k6 config I currently use (`<YOUR_DATADOG_API_KEY>` is replaced with an actual Datadog API key):

```
export const options = {
  vus: 5,
  duration: "10s",
  noConnectionReuse: true,
  ext: {
    loadimpact: {
      apm: [
        {
          provider: "datadog",
          api_key: "<YOUR_DATADOG_API_KEY>",
          include_test_run_id: true
        }
    ]
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the DataDog configuration for the commercial [k6 Cloud service](https://k6.io/cloud) (`k6 cloud`), not locally run k6 tests (`k6 run`). `test_run_id` is a concept in the cloud service, though it's also easy to emulate locally as a way to distinguish between test runs.

For local tests, you should enable the DataDog output by running k6 with `k6 run --out datadog script.js`. I assume you did that, otherwise you wouldn't see any metrics in DataDog.

Then, you can use the [`tags` option](https://k6.io/docs/using-k6/options#tags) to inject a unique extra tag for all metrics generated by a particular k6 run, so you can differentiate them in DataDog. For example:

```
k6 run --out datadog --tag test_run_id=1 script.js
k6 run --out datadog --tag test_run_id=2 script.js
k6 run --out datadog --tag test_run_id=3 script.js
...
```

Of course, you can choose any `key=value` combination, you are not restricted to `test_run_id`.

Answer (score 0):

One way to use the `test_run_id` inside the script is by adding it as tags inside the options.
Ex:

```
export const options = {
    
  tags: {
    test_run_id: 'my-test-run-id',
  },
};
```